# How can I list images used by running Docker containers?

Tags: docker

It's possible to list the running docker containers with `docker ps`, but how can I list the images used by them?

Comment: I'm not sure you differentiate "container" from "image". What do you mean "running images"? A Docker image itself cannot run, but you can create a container using an image. Do you want to list all images currently used by containers?

Comment: Yes, I want to list all the images used in the running Docker containers. I already knew the answer, but since it took me some time to figure it out, I wanted to share the solution using the "Answer your own question" feature of SO.

Comment: Ah indeed you answered your own question. Maybe clarifying what you mean by "listing running Docker images" by "listing images used by running containers" may help avoid confusion

Comment: You're right, I modified it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Listing running Docker images with their tag (registry/namespace/name:tag)

```bash
docker inspect --format '{{.Config.Image}}' $(docker ps --format='{{.ID}}')
```

1. List the IDs of the running containers with `docker ps --format='{{.ID}}'`
2. List the images associated with the containers with `docker inspect --format '{{.Config.Image}}' <containers_ids>`

#### Listing running Docker images with their digest (registry/namespace/name@digest)

```bash
docker image inspect --format '{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' $(docker inspect --format '{{.Image}}' $(docker ps --format='{{.ID}}'))
```

1. List the IDs of the running containers with `docker ps --format='{{.ID}}'`
2. List the images IDs associated with the containers with `docker inspect --format '{{.Image}}' <containers_ids>`
3. List the images associated with the images IDs with `docker image inspect --format '{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' <images_ids>`